# Is this nearly a plane wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, electrons

Let a plate of square shape (say 10x10 cm) is heated and can radiate an electron each second approximately. Is the Dirac wavefunction of every electron a nearly plane wave, e.g. in shape of a square?

Comment: In real world materials at room temperature the scattering length of electrons is pretty short, so the transverse coherence length of emitted electrons will be pretty small (nanometers or perhaps microns if you're lucky). There may be some special materials and special conditions where the scattering length is larger, but 10 centimeters seems like a real challenge.

Comment: @uhoh Why are you considering scattering? I mean radiation of atoms of the plate due to heating caused maybe by photon irradiation. The photon will have a wavelength of 10 cm and one wouldnt know in what point of the plate it was absorbed. So the whole plate will be the source (e.g. I believe every electron starts as a square plane)

Comment: @uhoh Also when it is nanometers no source can emit low energy electrons.

Comment: The mean free path of few eV electrons in most materials at room temperature is singles to tens of nanometers, can you find one that's over 100 nm or less than 1 nm?

Comment: @uhoh Are concidering a plate emiting electrons in air? What I mean is a plate in vacuum!

Comment: you won't have a wave in vacuum with a transverse coherence length of centimeters unless it was already centimeters in the emitter bulk. Since the coherence of the electrons while inside the emitter is short (units to tens of nanometers), emitted electrons are not going to have transverse coherence any larger than that.

Comment: @uhoh But does that mean that it is impossible to have a source of low energy electrons? As such a narrow (nm) wave should be a superposition of big spread of momenta via Heisenberg Uncertainty?